# Asserting True with two decompose objects with the same character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two unicode characters, both has same meaning. The `compat` character is a reference to the `origin` character which makes sense that both should be the same value but when I tried to assert their equality to a condition it returns `False` instead.

```py
origin = 'ᅢ'  # korean letter for: AE
compat = 'ㅐ'  # korean letter for: AE

print('origin', ascii(origin))
print('compat', ascii(compat), '\n')

decompose_origin = unicodedata.decomposition(origin)
decompose_compat = unicodedata.decomposition(compat)

print('decompose: origin', decompose_origin)
print('decompose: compat', decompose_compat, '\n')

# expected output: True
print(decompose_origin == decompose_compat)
```

```py
origin '\u1162'
compat '\u3150'

decompose: origin
decompose: compat <compat> 1162

False
```

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I found a library for this: https://github.com/jtauber/pyuca, but looking forward for a direct solution without third-party dependencies.

Comment: Is your question "how to compare these characters as equal"?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Normalize the strings to `NFKC` or `NFKD` normal form](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) to make them comparable:

```py
from unicodedata import normalize

origin = '\u1162'
compat = '\u3150'
for normal_form in ('NFC', 'NFD', 'NFKC', 'NFKD'):
    print(normal_form, ascii(normalize(normal_form, origin + ' == ' + compat)))
    print(normalize(normal_form, origin) == normalize(normal_form, compat))
# NFC '\u1162 == \u3150'
# False
# NFD '\u1162 == \u3150'
# False
# NFKC '\u1162 == \u1162'
# True
# NFKD '\u1162 == \u1162'
# True
```

Both `NFKC` and `NFKD` perform "compatibility decomposition, i.e. replace all compatibility characters with their equivalents". The `NFKC` normal form also applies canonical composition.

Comment: `unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', origin) == unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', compat)` Thank you so much.

Comment: I insist 'NFC' earlier but never had a chance to look 'NFKD', my bad.