# how can I compare two string of different font in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

[image]

In the image we can that both the string are same ( A word in Bengali language ). But the first one outputs False and Second one outputs True. I want both of them to output True.

```py
print('বাসায়'=='বাসায়')
print('বাসায়'=='বাসায়')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asserting True with two decompose objects with the same character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66514704/asserting-true-with-two-decompose-objects-with-the-same-character)

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the two strings *as text*, not an image? As the display of both is equal, it's not possible for us to assess the difference otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The following code solved my problem.

```
from unicodedata import normalize
normalize('NFKD','বাসায়') == normalize('NFKD','বাসায়')
```